# When is Fragment Ready in after instantiated in ViewPager PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have the following function in an Activity with ViewPager of 3 fragments

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, NewsListFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MinistriesListFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, NewsListFragment.class.getName()));

    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, mTabsName);


    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    Fragment newsfragment = ((PagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter()).getFragment(0);
    // Why is my newsfragment = null??

}
```

I'm trying toe get the Fragment, to set the listAdapter. However the fragment is still null even after added to the adapter. I tried getting it in onStart and onResume, it is still not successful.

Apparently the reason it is still null because the function below that is in pagerAdapter is still not called

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
```

Can someone shed some light, when should I call getFragment(xx) from my PagerAdapter? If I call at a later stage (e.g. swipe from ViewPager tab to tab), the fragment is there ready. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) for this purpose? You can easily implement your own adapter by overriding two of its methods: `getCount()` and `getItem(int)`. In this case you will be certain what you get when calling `adapter.getItem(0)`, etc.

Comment: Can u explain the use case for doing this..There can be a better alternative that both solves your problem as well as your purpose.

Comment: My use case is, in my activity, I am loading from the Web Server some data, that I plan to use to populate all my fragments. Once it is loaded, I will set the data to the List of each, and then populate it FragmentList. Currently I workaround with each Fragment performing it's own data download and load them up. Just though perhaps I could do one single load of data, and populate all the fragments.